# How can I tell LyX to differentiate between left Alt and right Alt (AltGr / 3rd Level)

Tags: lyx, keyboard

To increase my productivity, I would like so simplify some of the existing keyboard shortcuts (in particular Greek letters), by using either Left Alt or Right Alt in a non-interchangeable manner, i.e. so that LyX would perform a different action for `[Left Alt + F]` (open the file menu) and for `[Right Alt + F]` (insert the letter phi, for example).

Currently (on version 2.0.6), each of the keys is interpreted as the same `[Alt]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this only within LyX. You would have to do some hacking on LyX's code (in particular, how Qt handles key events).

One approach on Linux would be to use, e.g. xbindkeys to map your key combinations to different commands that execute LyX actions through the [LyX server](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXServer).

Comment: I see [what you mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283276/qt-left-ctrl-key-code) (I've posted there something about using [enum Qt::Key](http://ldc.usb.ve/docs/qt/qt.html#Key-enum), could you take a look?).

Comment: @Sparkler if you want LyX to consider adding support for this, make a feature request at http://www.lyx.org/trac . My guess is that it will not be implemented as many users don't know that the alt keys can be treated differently so it may confuse them.